# Printing serial number labels with Word and Mail Merge

Tags: microsoft-office, label-printer

I am trying to automate printing serial number labels in Microsoft Word.  I have a spreadsheet with one column called "start" and one called "end".

I want to create a word document that prints a range of labels from the spreadsheet.  For example, I have a row where start is "5" and end is "8", I'd like to print the following labels:
"This is widget 5"
"This is widget 6"
"This is widget 7"
"This is widget 8"

I have no way of knowing in advance exactly how many labels I'll need at a time, but it will be in the hundreds.

My first thought is to use either a mail merge or something with {SEQ}, but I can't get either one of them to loop over my range of numbers.  Any thoughts on how to do this, or at least where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Create your spreadsheet list manually with the max value. If the largest serial number (asset tag) is 200, then create your rows from 1 to 200. Once in word mail merge, filter your condition so you select greater than equal to 5 and less than equal to 8.